# how to increase performance of update statement using bulk collect

Tags: sql

how to use bulk collect for the below update statement if the update is to be run for more than 1 million records

```
Declare

Begin

update aa_item_tab
set desc='item cannot be null'
where item_type is null;

commit;

end;
```

Comment: People outside India aren't going to understand what are "lakh records". So please don't use Indian words here.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tag the database, but - that looks like Oracle to me.

Anyway: why do you think that bulk operation would improve anything? The simplest & most effective way to do that is to skip PL/SQL entirely and do everything at SQL level:

```
update aa_item_tab set desc='item cannot be null' where item_type is null;
```

That's all.

---

As you commented, you'd still want to try bulk collect; here's an example which is based on Scott's `EMP` table (as I don't have yours). I'll update `EMP.COMM` to `-1` if it is null.

Before:

```
SQL> select empno, ename, comm from emp where deptno = 30 order by ename;

     EMPNO ENAME            COMM
---------- ---------- ----------
      7499 ALLEN             300
      7698 BLAKE
      7900 JAMES
      7654 MARTIN           1400
      7844 TURNER              0
      7521 WARD              500

6 rows selected.
```

Anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_col sys.odcinumberlist;
  3  begin
  4    select e.empno
  5      bulk collect into l_col
  6      from emp e
  7      where e.deptno = 30
  8        and e.comm is null;
  9
 10    update emp e set
 11      e.comm = -1
 12      where e.empno in (select * from table(l_col));
 13  end;
 14  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

After:

```
SQL> select empno, ename, comm from emp where deptno = 30 order by ename;

     EMPNO ENAME            COMM
---------- ---------- ----------
      7499 ALLEN             300
      7698 BLAKE              -1
      7900 JAMES              -1
      7654 MARTIN           1400
      7844 TURNER              0
      7521 WARD              500

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: If the update statements are inside the plsql block..how do I do that

Comment: Put BEGIN in front of that UPDATE and END behind it (as you've already done, according to code you posted).

Comment: If I want to use bulk collect.. then how do I do

Comment: I edited the answer; have a look.